# azure blob storage cli count

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm testing some scripts and need a way to count how many blobs there are in a container.

I can list the blobs using:

```
az storage blob list --container-name "xxx" --account-key "xxx" --account-name "xxx" -o table
```

But how do I get a count?

I tried using --query length but it doesn't work.

Comment: I should mention that I'm using a windows machine and have Azure CLI installed locally (if that makes a difference?).

Comment: @Sajeetharan btw we can see your storage account key in your deleted answer. I don't think its a good idea to keep that exposed.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the amount of blob in one container with Azure CLI, please add `--query "length(@)"` in your command

```
az storage blob list -c "xxx" --account-key "xxx" --account-name "xxx" --query "length(@)" -o table
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I run `az storage blob list -c "xx" --account-key "xxx" --account-name "xx" --query "length(@)"` I get the following error: az storage blob list: error: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: 'length(@'

Comment: I tried the command posted by Jim and it ran perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I'm using Azure CLI from a windows machine and running the commands locally - I wonder if that makes a difference? I tried it exactly as above but doesnt work for me.

Comment: Ran it from my Windows machine as well (earlier I tried from my Mac) and it worked perfectly fine on both machines.

Comment: Tried again and same error. But at the bottom of the error I see: echo Failed to load python executable.

Comment: Check if python is installed? Simply type `python --version` in command prompt.

Comment: Python 3.8.3rc1

Comment: @amaru96 I run the command in Azure cloud shell :https://shell.azure.com. it is ok. Could you please which command-line tool you use?

Comment: @amaru96 Is that you get the error in the PowerShell?

Comment: Yes, thats the error I get when I run it in Powershell

Comment: @amaru96 According to my test, the PowerShell may not be able to read `)` in the string variable. Please change query as ` --query 'length(@")"' ` :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsBya.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/BARPy.png

Comment: @amaru96 Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: @amaru96 I have tested the suggestion from @jimXu and it works perfectly. You may want to mark it as an `Answer`. If you have any concern you my want to post your comment describing your concern.